# Preventing file upload by submitting a form which has file tag

Tags: ajax, file-upload

My client has millions of users driver website. I had to implement a custom file upload using AJAX/jQuery.

The file upload field is just needed to create a clickable and drop-downable file upload mechanism. Everything is working fine except when I submit the form it uploads the file again which has already been uploaded using ajax.

How can I prevent this uploading?

Comment: If you are sending the request once with AJAX, why are you submitting the form again?

Comment: Oh man, for other data

Comment: Why not send other data with the original AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the file input to outside the form or replace the file input with a new one when you upload the file.